# Providing one argument constructor to class

Tags: java

I made a one argument consturctor for the class below, but not sure how to assign it to the class variable colour.

```
public class MyClass{
   private String colour;
   public MyClass(String s){
   }
```

Please help ....

Comment: `colour = s;` ?

Comment: or `this.coclor=s`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyClass{
   private String color;
   public MyClass(String color){
      this.color = color;
   }
   ...
}
```